# Problem seeing XML declaration on System.Console

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have been experimenting with LINQ to XML and have run across a very basic problem.  For some reason, I am not seeing a XML declaration when dumping the tree to System.Console.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Build tree.
    XDocument xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

    // Output tree.
    System.Console.WriteLine(xd);

    // Pause.
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Can someone explain what basic thing I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some real data to the XDoc.  And be sure to use the Save() method to see the entire content:

```
  XDocument xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
  xd.Add(new XElement("top"));
  xd.Save(Console.Out);
```

Comment: Save has to be called on the in memory tree ?

Comment: Erm, not sure what you mean.  Use Save() to see the complete document, ToString() doesn't show everything.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Let me clarify: I thought Save() was used to serialize the in tree memory to disk but was not required to be called against the tree if it's in memory.

Comment: You don't have to call Save().  You'll get output without it.  However, I don't believe you'll get the same output (ie: the declaration will be missing) unless you save it to a stream.  nobugz "saved" the file to the Console's output stream, which is a clever way to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You document is empty, so you'll just see a newline (which will look blank).

Try adding something to the XML document.  This will print out a value XML doc:

```
// Build tree. 
XDocument xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
xd.AddFirst(new XElement("root"));

// Output tree. 
System.Console.WriteLine(xd);
```